# Im coding a discord bot for the first time and when i type node . my discord bot wont go online i dont know why

Tags: discord.js

this is my code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });

client.login("my token")
```

and when i run it and type node . into my terminal this is what happens

```
Error [DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.
    at WebSocketManager.createShards (/Users/sinanfarista/Desktop/discordBot#1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:250:15)
    at async Client.login (/Users/sinanfarista/Desktop/discordBot#1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:254:7) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'DISALLOWED_INTENTS'
}
```

Comment: Why do you have that intents part in the `Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });`?

Here is a small tutorial, try this maybe: https://gist.github.com/himanshuxd/3855d2699ed795279bba534e4ddc52f5

Answer (score 1):

you're probably attempting to use an intent that **hasn't been enabled**.

You must go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), select your application, navigate to the Bot section, and enable all of the intents. **(Or the ones you're currently using.)**

[image]